# c# ForEachAsync exits prematurely

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm trying to replace a simple foreach loop in my code by [Stephen Toub's implementation](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/implementing-a-simple-foreachasync-part-2/) of ForEachAsync.

So basically I have the following:

```
internal async Task GatherPreviousPositions(string companyId, long vehiculeId, AlertContract oneAlert, string positionTimeString, int positionInacurracyThreshold, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Look for previous positions
    var previousPositions = await DapperCommand.RunSQLCommandAsync<dynamic>(
        @"SELECT TOP 5 - ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY [Time] DESC) AS step ,[Time]
                              ,[VehiculeID]
                              ,[VehiculeUserID]
                              ,[Latitude]
                              ,[Longitude]
                              ,[Speed]
                              ,[Heading]
                              ,[Altitude]
                              ,[SatelliteCount]
                              ,[HDOP]
                              ,[VDOP]
                              ,[EngineOn]
                              ,[PrivacyOn]
                              ,[Mileage]
                              ,[DbInsertTime]
                              ,[ReceivedTime]
                          FROM [RTEGeoloc].[dbo].[GpsPosition]
                          WHERE [Time] < @Time
                            AND VehiculeID = @VehiculeID
                            ORDER BY [Time] DESC",
        new { Time = positionTimeString, VehiculeID = vehiculeId },
        true,
        "previousPositions",
        this.logger,
        null,
        false,
        cancellationToken)
        .ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);

        // Reverse gelocalize the positions
    foreach (dynamic pp in previousPositions)
    {
        double ppLatitude = (double)((IDictionary<string, object>)pp)["Latitude"];
        double ppLongitude = (double)((IDictionary<string, object>)pp)["Longitude"];
        string cacheKey = $@"{ppLatitude.RoundDown(5)},{ppLongitude.RoundDown(5)}";
        var addressOrPoi = await dataCache.GetOrCreateLazyAsync(key: cacheKey, dbKey: int.Parse(companyId, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture), $@"{ppLatitude};{ppLongitude}", factoryMethod: ReverseGeocodingFactory(), ct: cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

        oneAlert.AlertSteps.Add(new AlertStep
        {
            Age = oneAlert.TimestampAlertLocation != 0 ? oneAlert.TimestampAlertLocation - ((DateTime)((IDictionary<string, object>)pp)["Time"]).Ticks : 0,
            Step = $@"{(int)(long)((IDictionary<string, object>)pp)["step"]}",
            LocationName = addressOrPoi.Type == AlertLocationType.POI ? addressOrPoi.Value : string.Empty,
            DetailedMailingAddress = addressOrPoi.Address ?? string.Empty,
            Coordinate = new Coordinates { Latitude = (float)ppLatitude, Longitude = (float)ppLongitude },
            IsOldAlertLocation = false,
            IsInaccurateAlertLocation = ((IDictionary<string, object>)pp)["HDOP"] != null ? ToAccuracy((float)((IDictionary<string, object>)pp)["HDOP"]).GetValueOrDefault() > positionInacurracyThreshold : false,
            LocationSource = addressOrPoi.Type == AlertLocationType.POI ? "BALISE" : "GPS",
        });
    }
}
```

As you can see, I will collect up to 5 records from the database. I'd like to process them in parallel with a maximum concurrency of 4 Tasks.

The foreach loop becomes:

```
 await previousPositions.ForEachAsync(4, async pp =>
{
...
}).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

After this async foreach loop completes, I can see that `oneAlert.AlertSteps.Add(new AlertStep{...});` has only be called 4 times because I have 4 elements in my list no 5 as expected.

I have tested [numerous](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/212326/111978) [implementations](https://medium.com/@nirinchev/executing-a-collection-of-tasks-in-parallel-with-control-over-the-degree-of-parallelism-in-c-508d59ddffc6) found here and in blogs and they all suffer the same problem.

I'm missing something by I can't see what it is.

---

EDIT: Here is the solution to prevent the Race Condition during the Add calls.

```
   // Reverse gelocalize the positions
    using (SemaphoreSlim semaphoreSlim = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1))
    {
        //foreach (dynamic pp in previousPositions)
        await previousPositions.ForEachAsync(4,
        async pp =>
        {
            double ppLatitude = (double)((IDictionary<string, object>)pp)["Latitude"];
            double ppLongitude = (double)((IDictionary<string, object>)pp)["Longitude"];
            string cacheKey = $@"{ppLatitude.RoundDown(5)},{ppLongitude.RoundDown(5)}";
            var addressOrPoi = await dataCache.GetOrCreateLazyAsync(key: cacheKey, dbKey: int.Parse(companyId, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture), $@"{ppLatitude};{ppLongitude}", factoryMethod: ReverseGeocodingFactory(), ct: cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

            await semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            try
            {
                oneAlert.AlertSteps.Add(new AlertStep
                {
                    Age = oneAlert.TimestampAlertLocation != 0 ? oneAlert.TimestampAlertLocation - ((DateTime)((IDictionary<string, object>)pp)["Time"]).Ticks : 0,
                    Step = $@"{(int)(long)((IDictionary<string, object>)pp)["step"]}",
                    LocationName = addressOrPoi.Type == AlertLocationType.POI ? addressOrPoi.Value : string.Empty,
                    DetailedMailingAddress = addressOrPoi.Address ?? string.Empty,
                    Coordinate = new Coordinates { Latitude = (float)ppLatitude, Longitude = (float)ppLongitude },
                    IsOldAlertLocation = false,
                    IsInaccurateAlertLocation = ((IDictionary<string, object>)pp)["HDOP"] != null ? ToAccuracy((float)((IDictionary<string, object>)pp)["HDOP"]).GetValueOrDefault() > positionInacurracyThreshold : false,
                    LocationSource = addressOrPoi.Type == AlertLocationType.POI ? "BALISE" : "GPS",
                });
            }
            finally
            {
                semaphoreSlim.Release();
            }
        }).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

Comment: Are the data structures you use thread-safe? If not, then you almost certainly got into a race condition that lost an item. If they aren't, and you can't switch to a thread-safe collection, use a lock around the section of code manipulating the collection to serialize access to it.

Comment: ie. try this: `var alertStep = new AlertStep { ... }; lock (oneAlert) { oneAlert.Add(alertStep); }`, though, you probably shouldn't lock on the list object, you should have a separate object, of type `object`, that you use for synchronization here, private to your threading code (but it must be shared between all parallel threads in this foreach)

Comment: Of couse this should be a race condition! Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction.  `SemaphoreSlim` I'm coming...

Comment: Note that I cannot guarantee that this is the cause of your issue, it's just the usual suspect, so try that first and hopefully it will fix it, but there is still a slim chance you'll still have a problem, but then because of something else.

Comment: You are reading stream data results for the database which is different from the link you provided.  What I think is happening (not sure) that the end of stream is causing the query to terminate when it sees the end of stream.  Try removing the await.  I don't think you need both the async and await.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Introducing a SemaphoreSlim  around the ForechAsync and awaiting it before the Add solved my problem.